# Find the rank of the linear transformation

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space of all $n\times n$ real matrices.

If $T: M_n(\mathbb{R})\to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear transformation such that $T(A)=0$ whenever $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$
is symmetric or skew-symmetric, the rank of $T$ is

A. $n(n+1)/2$
B. $n(n-1)/2$
C. $n$
D. $0$

here answer is 0 how i get 0

Answer (score 2):

Hint: every $n\times n$ matrix is the sum of a symmetric matrix with a skew-symmetric matrix.

Further hint: if $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, write $A=X+Y$, where $X$ is symmetric and $Y$ is skew-symmetric. Then $T(A)=T(X)+T(Y)=\dots$; therefore$\,\dots$